# How to safely remove directory tree in script with path defined by a variable

Tags: bash, security, rm, safety

This is a very basic question, and surely has been asked before, but I am having trouble finding the answer or guidance. There are e.g. these but they don't quite hit the mark:

- [How to safely remove all files (including hidden files) from current directory (after cding to that directory)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653796/how-to-safely-remove-all-files-including-hidden-files-from-current-directory)
- [Safely define an environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442346/safely-define-an-environment-variable)

Essentially I just want to remove a temporary directory tree as part of a
bash script, like so

```
rm -rf $my_path
```

But I'm a bit paranoid that somewhere else in the script it could be possible for `$my_path` to
expand out into `/` or something equally bad. For example if somewhere there is `my_path=$var1/$var2` and both `$var1` and `$var2` end up defaulting to empty strings or some such.

What is the best practice way to write this kind of command into a script to avoid accidental enormous problems?

Comment: Validate `$var1` and `$var2` at the points they are defined. If `$myvar` is critical then validate it when it's defined. There are only so many ways you can protect an `rm` (is it `/` or `$HOME`, etc) but you should consider what else has already expected it to have a meaningful value

Comment: `rm --preserve-root=all -Ir -- "$my_path"`